# Email Columns on Android

Tags: android, html, css, html-email

I'm working on a new Email design for myself, and I've gotten it to work on everything but Android. The two columns don't have an even width when viewed on Android.

```css
            /* Some resets and issue fixes */
        #outlook a { padding:0; }
            body{ width:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; }
            .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
            .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
            .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:100%;!important;}
            table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
            .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%;}
            div[style*=margin: 16px 0;]{
       margin:0 !important;
      }
        
    @media screen and (max-width: 630px){
    *[class="100p"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
    *[class="condensed"] {padding-bottom:20px !important; display: block; width:100% !important; text-align: center !important;}
     *[class="center"] {text-align:center !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
     *[class="100padleftright"] {width:100% !important; padding:0 20px 0 20px;}
     *[class="100padtopbottom"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;}
        }
```

```html
<table><tr>
            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100padtopbottom" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #F4F4F4;border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="condensed" style="padding-top: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 260px;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: center;"><img align="center" class="columnImage" src="https://www.skirball.org/sites/default/files/styles/content_desktop/public/social_good_salon_hotel_usa.jpg?itok=uKMG5iih&amp;timestamp=1500073852" style="width:100%;max-width: 260px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;" width="260"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: left;" valign="top">
                                    <h3 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;color: #606060 !important;">Social Good Salon</h3>
                                    The Skirball’s Social Good Salons are regular gatherings where people of all backgrounds and ages are welcome to learn about current events and socially relevant topics and then exchange ideas and opinions. At this salon, begin by watching the New York Times Op-Doc Hotel U.S.A. (2017)—Andrea Meller and Marissa Pearl’s short about the exciting and bewildering experience of a refugee’s very first night in the United States. After the screenings, participate in a facilitated small group discussion of the film’s themes, while enjoying complimentary coffee, tea, and cookies.<br>
                                    <a href="https://www.skirball.org/programs/words-and-ideas/social-good-salon" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">See more details here!</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" class="condensed" style="padding-top: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 260px;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: center;"><img class="columnImage" src="https://www.skirball.org/sites/default/files/styles/content_desktop/public/17.8-pst-free-days.jpg?itok=72B9pnSU&amp;timestamp=1504731793" style="width:100%; max-width: 260px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;" width="260"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: left;" valign="top">
                                    <h3 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;color: #606060 !important;">LA Free Day</h3>
                                    On October 28, enjoy complimentary admission to view the Skirball’s Pacific Standard Time: LA/LA exhibitions, <a href="https://www.skirball.org/exhibitions/another-promised-land-anita-brenners-mexico" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Another Promised Land: Anita Brenner’s Mexico</a> and <a href="https://www.skirball.org/exhibitions/surface-tension-ken-gonzales-day" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Surface Tension by Ken Gonzales-Day: Murals, Signs, and Mark‐Making in LA.</a><br>
                                    For a list of all PST: LA/LA institutions in the West LA and Valley region participating in this FREE day, visit <a href="http://www.pacificstandardtime.org/" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">pacificstandardtime.org</a>.<br>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="https://www.skirball.org/programs/special-event/pacific-standard-time-lala-free-day-west-la-and-valley-region" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Check it Out Here!</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- // END COLUMNS --></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What email client are you testing on (on android)? How about making the columns into rows on Android?

Comment: I am testing on Litmus, Testing for Gmail (Android) and Android 4.

Comment: Your best bet will be breaking it into columns.2 columns resize in a weird way

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your code and you are dropping it into two columns on iOS and devices that support media queries. Android 4.1 had an update to its rendering engine back in the day and display block on `td` stopped working. Display block however works on `th`.

I have only changed the td to th and added font-weight normal to your code.

```css
 /* Some resets and issue fixes */
 #outlook a { padding:0; }
 body{ width:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; }
 .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
 .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
 .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:100%;!important;}
 table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
 .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%;}
 div[style*=margin: 16px 0;]{
 margin:0 !important;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 630px){
 *[class="100p"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
 *[class="condensed"] {padding-bottom:20px !important; display: block; width:100% !important; text-align: center !important;}
 *[class="center"] {text-align:center !important; width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
 *[class="100padleftright"] {width:100% !important; padding:0 20px 0 20px;}
 *[class="100padtopbottom"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;}
 }
```

```html
<table><tr>
            <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="100padtopbottom" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;background-color: #F4F4F4;border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th align="center" class="condensed" style="padding-top: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 260px;font-weight:normal;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: center;"><img align="center" class="columnImage" src="https://www.skirball.org/sites/default/files/styles/content_desktop/public/social_good_salon_hotel_usa.jpg?itok=uKMG5iih&amp;timestamp=1500073852" style="width:100%;max-width: 260px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;" width="260"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: left;" valign="top">
                                    <h3 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;color: #606060 !important;">Social Good Salon</h3>
                                    The Skirball’s Social Good Salons are regular gatherings where people of all backgrounds and ages are welcome to learn about current events and socially relevant topics and then exchange ideas and opinions. At this salon, begin by watching the New York Times Op-Doc Hotel U.S.A. (2017)—Andrea Meller and Marissa Pearl’s short about the exciting and bewildering experience of a refugee’s very first night in the United States. After the screenings, participate in a facilitated small group discussion of the film’s themes, while enjoying complimentary coffee, tea, and cookies.<br>
                                    <a href="https://www.skirball.org/programs/words-and-ideas/social-good-salon" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">See more details here!</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </th>
                        <th align="center" class="condensed" style="padding-top: 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;width: 260px;font-weight:normal;" valign="top">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;border-collapse: collapse !important;" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: center;"><img class="columnImage" src="https://www.skirball.org/sites/default/files/styles/content_desktop/public/17.8-pst-free-days.jpg?itok=72B9pnSU&amp;timestamp=1504731793" style="width:100%; max-width: 260px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;" width="260"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="100padleftright" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;color: #505050;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;padding-top: 0;padding-right: 20px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 20px;text-align: left;" valign="top">
                                    <h3 style="display: block;font-family: Helvetica;font-size: 16px;font-style: italic;font-weight: normal;line-height: 100%;letter-spacing: normal;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;color: #606060 !important;">LA Free Day</h3>
                                    On October 28, enjoy complimentary admission to view the Skirball’s Pacific Standard Time: LA/LA exhibitions, <a href="https://www.skirball.org/exhibitions/another-promised-land-anita-brenners-mexico" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Another Promised Land: Anita Brenner’s Mexico</a> and <a href="https://www.skirball.org/exhibitions/surface-tension-ken-gonzales-day" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Surface Tension by Ken Gonzales-Day: Murals, Signs, and Mark‐Making in LA.</a><br>
                                    For a list of all PST: LA/LA institutions in the West LA and Valley region participating in this FREE day, visit <a href="http://www.pacificstandardtime.org/" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">pacificstandardtime.org</a>.<br>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="https://www.skirball.org/programs/special-event/pacific-standard-time-lala-free-day-west-la-and-valley-region" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;color: #EB4102;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">Check it Out Here!</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!-- // END COLUMNS --></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Hope this works for you.